Why does the NIV have differing versions of Romans 3:22?
I've seen different translations render differing versions of the same words, but the NIV seems to have a difference with itself over Romans 3:22 (YouVersion NIV shown, emphasis mine)

This righteousness is given through faith in Jesus Christ to all who believe. There is no difference between Jew and Gentile

All other translations omit the highlighted part. What's strange is some versions of the NIV also have it like that. I have a NIV 1984 and it does not have the highlighted part. How did it get in there and why do some NIV versions not have it?

It's just making the implicit explicit. The whole context of Romans 2-3 is clearly about Jews and Gentiles. It's adding a detail that's not there in the original Greek, but as far as insertions go it's very innocuous.

There is no warrant to add the wording and no warrant to restrict the force of 'there is no difference' as it relates to all who believe . . . . .  irrespective of origin. For there is a great deal of self-righteousness within the Gentile nations. Romans brings this home forcibly to all of Adam's race not just self-righteousness within the Jewish nation. Up-voted +1. Well spotted.

The NIV sought to clarify Paul's meaning, and it is not alone in doing so. Others include:

AMP -
This righteousness of God comes through faith in Jesus Christ for all those [Jew or Gentile] who believe [and trust in Him and acknowledge Him as God’s Son]. There is no distinction,

CJB -
and it is a righteousness that comes from God, through the faithfulness of Yeshua the Messiah, to all who continue trusting. For it makes no difference whether one is a Jew or a Gentile,

EASY -
God accepts people as right with himself because Jesus Christ did what God wanted. God accepts every person who believes in Christ. It is the same way for everyone, whether they are Jews or Gentiles.


However, the fact remains that the text itself does not make the clarification that these translations add. Well intended though they may be, they (with the exception of AMP) add these words without notice. This is analogous to publishing a version of the U.S. Declaration of Independence as follows:

We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created
equal before the law.

This is certainly closer to what Jefferson meant, since he knew well that people are not created equal in terms of talents. However, the addition of "before the law" is inappropriate unless it appears in brackets on as a footnote. NIV got the meaning right, but did not show a proper respect for the text.

That's hard on NIV - the way they respect the text is by making it easier for children to follow. To translate at all is a respectful, and in their case very probably a praiseful, endeavour. But if a framework is so severe as to fault NIV on this point (when there are so many others, with this one at least getting the meaning right), it should better say that to translate at all is disrespectful. The analogy to the DoI doesn't hold because the original can still be read - in 2000 years' time they really might want to add before the law in translation, if they're going for readability

Making the bible accessible to children is a noble goal indeed. I'm sure the NIV editors' hearts are in the right place in that regard but IMO it would be better to put the clarification in brackets rather than making it seem it is in the original.

This isn't a textual variant (Nestle-Aland's small critical apparatus, 1994).
The words "between Jew and Gentile" don't exist in the original, and have been added by NIV sometime between 1984 and 2011 to explain what sort of difference is referred to.
And they wouldn't do that lightly, so probably there is some sort of serious confusion, being reported to the translators as feedback from the pastors who use this bible. (In the UK the NIV is the free giveaway bible). It's easy to imagine people in home-groups interpreting it in an 'anything-goes' way, such as with Jesus 'replacing the prophets'.
To find out exactly why they did it would require commentary from the translators. Something like this probably won't be in the notes in the back of the bible, though. This is a serious problem of bibles: showing their workings (as is done in a StackExchange) would need a book a hundred times longer that no-one would buy! This concession-to-the-practical leads to a four word amendment by NIV intellectually shufting a question onto the OP that needs 100 words to ask it and deserves an answer of 300 words.
The NIV is allowed to have differences with itself - it's very much an active-usage, mission-focused bible that concentrates on reader-comprehension. If translation-philosophy is at all of interest, it's probably not the bible to be using.
